# Apache conditional redirection of assets url

Tags: apache, redirect, conditional-statements, assets

I'm a beginner with apache and I have an issue:

when I type https://my.example.dev?prev=XYZ I want apache to redirect all my theme urls (assets)

I have this apache redirection that changes my website theme:

```
`   RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} prev=([^&]+)
    RewriteRule ^/theme/(.*)$ https://%1.example.dev/theme/$1
```

but it work only when i type the theme url ( ex: https://my.example.dev/theme/css/style.css?prev=XXX )